# S3 / Cloudfront Download Restrictions

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using S3 and Cloudfront for an application deployed on EC2.

The permissions seem (in my limited knowledge of AWS) to be either public or private. How can I make files accessible from Cloudfront / S3 to requests from my EC2 instances, but not elsewhere?

I'm sure I'm probably just missing something in the AWS console.

Any ideas welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are the owner and you have S3 & EC2 on the same account, then make your files Read/Write only to you. **Give permission (Full Control) only to the `owner`.**

To understand Amazon S3 ACL - please read this article: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?ManageACLsUsingConsole.html

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has a guide on how to do this with S3 permissions and CloudFront:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?SecuringContent_S3.html